# Is it possible to communicate mobile to embedded devices through ultrasonic audio signal

Tags: embedded, communication

I am looking for a wireless communication technology for exchanging data between devices via sound in ultrasonic frequencies.It is possible to communicate with two mobile devices.I want to communicate a mobile and an embedded device.Is it possible?Any device is working with this protocol?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about software development.  Belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.  For what it is worth the idea has a number of problems and there are much simpler and more conventional infra-red (optical) and radio (RF) methods.  Additional hardware will be required on the mobile device, and US transducers are relatively large and power hungry.  Reliable data rate is also likely to be very low given a typical 40KHz carrier.

Comment: One problem is the ease disrupting the signal.  If you ever encounter a robot using US object avoidance, try shaking your keys near it; it is likely to get very confused if it does not have other sensor types to fall back on - the frequencies generated extend well into the ultrasonic range.

Comment: The microphone and speaker on a mobile phone cannot receive or transmit ultrasonic signals, so you would need external components without low-pass filters to send and receive ultrasound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible.  Back in the 1970's my TV remote control used ultrasound to change the channel and turn the TV off.  The control was somewhat rudimentary IIRC a short press changed the channel up and a long press turned the TV off.  It worked quite reliably for these functions.

Providing more functionality would require a more complicated modulation scheme which, as has been said in another answer, would be prone to interference from other sound sources.  This probably explains why infra-red communucation signals are used in more modern remote control systems.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible - why shouldn't it be? Smartphones are just embedded computers too.  I imagine getting CE/FCC/etc certifications with such an embedded device will not be so easy. And production testing ...

But is it feasible? Probably not. Power consumption is a lot higher than with any RF-link, it's more susceptible to noise (quite literally) and the required components (microphone+speaker) are bigger than RF-components (antenna).

And then there's a whole bunch of other things you need to keep in mind when working with ultrasound, starting with the plastic design of the embedded device. But also things like the effect of ultrasound on people and their pets etc.

Comment: If it is possible what are the components  required other than microphone and speaker.

Comment: well in principle, thats all. ofcourse you'll need a microprocessor and whatever components required for power supply of the speaker and processor. a reliable clock-source will probably help. and for high-speed modulation, you'll want to look into DSPs.